# how to create a new start session in sql server 2008 with user from other computer?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, lan, workgroup

I have two computers. One with windows XP where I have SQL Server 2008 Express and other computer with windows 7. In both computers I have sql  server management studio.

Both computers are in the same work group. With explorer I can see the shared folder from one computer to each other.

In the windows 7 computer, when in explorer I put \myXPComputer I can see the folder that are shared and a conection that is sqlexpress. If I do doulbe click in this icon I get an error that say that windows can't access to \myXPComputer\slqexpress. However I can connect to the printers that are shared and they are in the xp computer.

So in the xp computer, I open sql server management studio and I try to add a new start session, but I only can see the location \myXPComputer, I can`t select other users from other computers in the same workgroup.

I would like to know kow can access to the database in XP from sql server management studio installed in my windows 7 computer.

Thanks.

Comment: remote desktop is not an option? you definitely want to use MANAGEMENT Studio of Windows 7?

Comment: Well, I want to use ssms in windows 7 to try to connect to sql server from other computer. Really the idea is to use an application that use EF to connect to the database. But I have problems, so I think the easy to discard problems is try to connect with ssms, and if I can, solve the problems with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS...

Server type: Database Engine:
Server name: the IP of the computer you're connecting to.

Authentication...

you can do windows, but it's harder to set up so let's not.  So... make sure your SQL server supports mixed mode authentication and use the credentials of the SQL server you're connecting to, so if you're on 7 and trying to connect to xp, put in the IP of that xp box and the credentials that let you login to that xp box.  Those credentials are probably SA.  If not, make sure you have mixed mode & SA enabled.

This is the very basic jist of it.

Comment: yes, I know that I can use mixed mode, but I would like to use only windows athentication because the objetive is to use an application that use EF and I would like to avoid the needed of have in the connection string the user and password for security reasons.

Comment: well windows auth isn't really for cross server (computer in your case) authentication.  The way I'd do it is I'd run SSMS as the user from the other computer, who I would add to the current one effectively spoofing the user windows auth passes through.